# How to access the website at root dir instead of the WordPress install dir?

Tags: home-url

I've installed Wordpress via cPanel into https://mywww.com/wp.
The same https://mywww.com/wp is used as my Site Address (URL).

I'd like to access my site at https://mywww.com, however, when I change this in the Wordpress General Settings, the site does not work.

What do I need to do to leave the WordPress installation in the wp directory, but access the site at the root?

Comment: you can tell WP it lives at `mywww.com/` but unless you modify your server to route the requests to `/wp/index.php` they'll never reach WordPress. Apache/Nginx changes would be necessary, or an additional set of files one level up.

Comment: Should I just move all `/myweb/wp` files down to `/myweb`? Is it late to do that now?

Comment: yes you could do that, but keep a backup just in case, and be careful that paths referencing `/wp` will be broken unless you handle them

Comment: This link should help: [Giving Wordpress it's own directory](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/)

Comment: OK: I backed up the WordPress dir to `wp-old`, then copied `wp-old` down to my root dir, and finally searched through my cPanel WP database and replaced all `myweb.com/wp/` with `myweb.com`. Finally, clear all your test browser cash or test in annonimous tab! Some work there. I still don't understand why hasn't the WordPress installation via cPanel warned me about the consequences of installing the WP in own dir.